# Where is the image being uploaded?

Tags: python, django, image, django-rest-framework

I have created a custom User model in django:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30)
    image = models.ImageField(_('profile image'), upload_to='userimages/', default = 'user_default.jpeg')
```

Now I have created a serializer for django-rest-framework to register a new user:

```
class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'},
                                     write_only=True,
                                     validators=settings.get('PASSWORD_VALIDATORS'))
    image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = tuple(User.REQUIRED_FIELDS) + (
            User.USERNAME_FIELD,
            User._meta.pk.name,
            'image',
            'password',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if settings.get('SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL'):
            with transaction.atomic():
                user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
                user.is_active = False
                user.save(update_fields=['is_active'])
        else:
            user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
```

My media settings are:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

My 'urls.py':

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('app.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Now when I 'POST' on the /register/ endpoint, the User gets created and I am able to see the image in the browser from the url in admin panel. But when I look into my project directory, the image is just not there. I am not able to figure out the image location. I am pretty sure that the image gets uploaded in my computer as I tried uploading it from some other device on LAN and was able to access it (from the browser)after disconnecting from the other computer.

Please help.

Comment: what is BASE_DIR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is just to know your folder's location, you can run the following command (In linux-based systems):

```
sudo find / -name userimages
```

Comment: After running this, I found that it has created the media at /media/userimages/. Now the thing is, I don't understnd this behaviour.

Comment: You mean that you have `/media/media/userimages/`?

Comment: Just /media/userimages/

Comment: It is the normal behavior, you specified `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`, this means `media` folder is located in your project's base folder. Then `upload_to='userimages/'` means `userimages` would be created in `your_project/media/`

Comment: but my BASE_DIR is my project's root folder. The folder being created is in computer's root directory

Comment: Create a file in the same level as `settings.py` (let's say `test.py`) with this content `import os; print(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))`, and let me know what's the result when you run `python test.py`

Comment: If your program was able to create `/media/userimages/`, it also means that you are running your project as root, which you should **never** do. When developing, you should run it in your user account. When in production, it should have its own user account. Otherwise you're exposing your root account to an inherently insecure program that's itself exposed to the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that user uploaded files should be stored in MEDIA_ROOT.

You can check this location by firing up the Django shell and checking on setting:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.MEDIA_ROOT
<< snip: the media root location >>
```

Comment: when i hardcoded the path to media folder, its gets uploaded to the folder.

Comment: @toothie: but this is strange, in the code in your question you say settings.MEDIA_ROOT is BASE_DIR + 'media', and now it says '/media/'? Appears the code in your question isn't what you actually have.

Comment: So that would be `/media/` on your file system. E.g. in a folder called "media" that's directly below the root of your file system.